# How to upload user datato firestore with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, user-data

I am trying to upload some data but when I excute the function it gives me this error:

> `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Firestore' of 'function result'`
> I don't know what this mean because I am new to flutter so I need any help,
> also this is the function I tried
> code:

```
static Future uploaduserdata(
      String userName, String age, String nat, String email) async {
    FirebaseUser curuser = await _auth.currentUser();
    _firestore.collection("users").document(curuser.uid).setData({
      'userName': userName,
      'age': age,
      'email': email,
      'nationality': nat
    }).then((_) {
      print("success!");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using `.then()` in an `async` function?

Comment: Don't know as I am learning on a tutorial  [https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/]

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] and tell us where *exactly* this error occurs (which line)?

Comment: I think It happens in the setData section, maybe because the data I am entering as a list isn't defined for firestore 'as a list'.

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate which line of code the error is on, and the values of all the variables in use here.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using what you've given, and what you have no is incomplete.